# How to create the inverse where in a sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table with the fields FamilyId, Relation, RegId, EmailAddress. Relation can be Head, Partner, Child and Other (always 1 Head).
I need 2 sql queries:

1- to determine the number of families with at least 1 email address

2- to determine the number of families with no email addres at all (none of the members)

These two results should add up to the total of the number of families.

As first query I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1.FamilyId
FROM Family AS C1, Family AS C2
WHERE C1.FamilyId=C2.FamilyId AND C1.Relation="HEAD" AND C2.EmailAddress IS NOT Null;
```

How to write the inverse where??

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms .

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?!? In ANSI SQL, double quotes are for delimited identifiers, i.e. `"HEAD"` is considered to be a column name. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'HEAD'`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: And only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to make the query, but one way is using `EXISTS`, for which the inverse is `NOT EXISTS`.

As you need the *number* of families, you'd need to return a count.

So the first query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Family AS C1
WHERE  C1.Relation = 'HEAD'
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM  Family AS C2
               WHERE C1.FamilyId = C2.FamilyId 
               AND   C2.EmailAddress IS NOT NULL)
```

Change to `NOT EXISTS` for the second query.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is giving you correct results for the first question then you can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FamilyId
FROM Family
Where FamilyId NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT C1.FamilyId
FROM Family AS C1, Family AS C2
WHERE C1.FamilyId=C2.FamilyId AND C1.Relation="HEAD" AND C2.EmailAddress IS NOT Null);
```

Note that you should be using the modern join syntax `INNER JOIN` instead of  `FROM Family AS C1, Family AS C2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it solve your problem:

```
SELECT FamilyId
FROM Family
WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL AND Relation <> "HEAD"
Group By FamilyId
HAVING Count(DISTINCT EmailAdress) > 0
```

Comment: Your HAVING clause makes no difference. The WHERE clause prohibits null EmailAdresses.

Comment: @jarlh Yes it does; this is the thing that exists in WHERE clause of question. I guess Jan needs to count email addresses other than NULL values.

Comment: The WHERE clause will pass non-null EmailAddress only. I.e. HAVING's `Count(DISTINCT EmailAdress)` will _always_ be > 0.

Comment: @jarlh Now I got what you meant. I understand.